# Observer pattern for Yammer api

Tags: yammer

I am using Yammer api (Java script SDK) for integrating Yammer Platform into our app. The problem is "when I am submitting a post from my app, it's getting updated on Yammer Platform, but when I do post from Yammer Platform, my app is not getting updated". So I would like to know whether there is any observer pattern for Yammer api in Java script sdk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. In my app I'm issuing GET request for messages to refresh data on the client side.

Comment: how does this help answer the question?